# How can I get the Bridged IP address of a VirtualBox VM running in headless mode?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-access

I have VirtualBox set up on a server.  It was set up as a Bridged VM, and has an IP address.  It's now running in headless mode, started with "VBoxHeadless -s PuppetMaster".

How can I find out what IP the VM is using VBoxManage?

Answer (score 21):

I could find my Headless VB with the combination of following commands:

```
# Update arp table
for i in {1..254}; do ping -c 1 192.168.178.$i & done

# Find vm name
VBoxManage list runningvms

# Find MAC: subsitute vmname with your vm's name
VBoxManage showvminfo vmname

# Find IP: substitute vname-mac-addr with your vm's mac address in ':' notation
arp -a | grep vmname-mac-addr
```

But even easier: in linux, you can connect to the VB:

```
# Default VirtualBox Listening Port: 3389
rdesktop -N hostingserver:3389
```

This command will open a shell window, and you'll have direct access to the Headless VB, where you can retrieve your Headless VB IP:
    ip addr

Comment: I've translated it into golang program https://gist.github.com/mhewedy/352ddb55d4740945d0462df91aece198 I hope I could upload the binary file for ease use by others.

Answer (score 6):

Install guest additions and (assuming linux is the guest) you can run the following:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol yourVirtualMachineName execute --image "/sbin/ifconfig"  --username yourUser --password yourPassword --wait-exit --wait-stdout -- -a
```

Comment: Format changed a bit now, you'll need `VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol yourVirtualMachineName --username yourUser --password yourPassword run -- /sbin/ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 4):

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate {`VBoxManage list runningvms | awk -F"{" '{print $2}'` | grep IP | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Command works for a single VM. -- With multiple VMs filter by VM name, e.g.: `VBoxManage list runningvms | grep vmname | awk ...`

Comment: Or we can inquire about a specific VM. e.g. `VBoxManage guestproperty get <vm-name> "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" | cut -f2 -d " "`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if VBoxManage can give you that information directly. What you can do is run the following command to see the network card configuration.

```
VBoxManage showvminfo PuppetMaster | egrep ^NIC
```

That will if nothing else will provide you with the MAC address, allowing you to find out the actual ip address by other means.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the IP using the MAC address from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

You can get it directly using this command:

```
VBoxManage list bridgedifs
```

Comment: For me this shows only the address that I'm sharing, not what the client actually gets.

Answer (score 3):

From [virtualbox.org](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36592) forum --

`VBoxManage guestproperty get <vm-name> "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP" | cut -f2 -d " "`

Comment: Nice option. Just noting comment from the forum: "From my testing, it seems the guest properties are only available if the guest VM has the Guest Additions installed." Indeed, I have no guest additions and get "No value set!".

Answer (score 0):

Without guest additions, on a Windows host, and unable to `rdesktop` into the VM, [this is what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532457/5362795):

Get MAC of virtual machine (WSL Linux) and scan the network:

```
VBoxManage.exe showvminfo $vmname | grep MAC     # get MAC address
nmap 192.168.178.* -p 22 | grep open -B 5        # Find machines ready to SSH
```

The scan itself showed me the desired IP, but I can confirm it on the PowerShell, using the MAC I got earlier. For example:

```
arp -a | findstr -i 08-00-27-9A-49-B6
```

Output is like:

```
192.168.178.30        08-00-27-9a-49-b6     dynamic
```

And that confirms the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script I put together to get the IP of my Vbox VM.

#!/bin/bash

Knowing my VM is named 'ubuntu22'
uuid_raw=$(vboxmanage list runningvms | grep ubuntu)
UUID "ubuntu22" {6eac6956-2952-425f-ba20-e865d0970e33}
uuid=$(echo $uuid_raw | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | sed s/{// | sed s/}//)
echo "UUID ${uuid}"
mac=$(vboxmanage showvminfo --details ${uuid} | grep MAC | awk -F'MAC: ' '{print $2}'| awk -F',' '{print $1}')
arp -a  | sed s/://g | grep -i $mac

---

Yields the following output:

UUID 90dcc1dc-e14d-4362-bc7e-c3f58698beb9
? (10.1.50.193) at 080027fd0e63 [ether] on eno1